# How to get the TextField value in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have created sign up screen in the flutter. I want to get the email and password in the `onPressed` of the `FlatButton`.

Does anyone know how to do this in flutter ?

```
  Widget SignupPage() {
    return new Scaffold(body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        image: DecorationImage(
          colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05), BlendMode.dstATop),
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/mountains.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.headset_mic,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "EMAIL",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "PASSWORD",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: '*********',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "CONFIRM PASSWORD",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    width: 0.5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: '*********',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 24.0,
          ),
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    "Already have an account?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 50.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new FlatButton(
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    onPressed: () => authHandler.handleSignInEmail(emailController.text, passwordController.text)
                        .then((FirebaseUser user) {
                      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                    }).catchError((e) => print(e)),
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 20.0,
                        horizontal: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "SIGN UP",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Create your `TextEditingController` as a global variable in your `State` class and set it into your `TextField` widget.

```
final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
```

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

```
TextField(
  controller: emailController,
  obscureText: true,
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
  ),
)
```

Now you can get the value using :

```
emailController.text
```

You can get more information here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

Comment: I have 3 TextFields, I need 3 TextEditingController?

Comment: yes, or you can use the onChanged method of each textfield and save the value into a local var for each textfield

Comment: @diegoveloper I have 10 textfields and dropdownbuttons fields in a form. Is there any method to get all the elements value? Or will I have to fetch value one by one of each element by TextEditingController.text function? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be `Stateful` widget?

Comment: yes, otherwise your texteditingcontroller will be destroyed every time you rebuild any widget above your stateless

Answer (score 22):

another easier (for my opinion) option is to add 'onChanged' property inside the TextField class that will contain the String

`String enteredText .... TextField( onChanged: (newText) { enteredText = newText; },`

Comment: `onChanged` will be triggered for every single character changed, am I right?

Comment: @HasanAbdullah Yes, you're right

Answer (score 10):

The text field calls the `onChanged` callback whenever the user changes the text in the field. If the user indicates that they are done typing in the field (e.g., by pressing a button on the soft keyboard), the text field calls the `onSubmitted` callback.

Using this callbacks, we can set the `instance variables` and use those variables on `onPress` of submit button.

Answer (score 9):

**Make the TextEditingController before the build method.**

```
TextEditingController yourControllerName = new TextEditingController();
```

**Then in TextField, pass controller like this:**

```
TextField(
           controller: yourNameController,
           // your extra stuff
          )
```

**And Suppose you want to access it in a Text, access it like this:**

```
Text(
     yourControllerName.text.toString(), // this will convert your controller to String
     )
```

Thanks, I hope it works!!!