# Flutter : How to get value from TextField

Tags: flutter, textfield

```
class _UpdateViewState extends State<UpdateView> {
  var dropDownValue = "Vaccine";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void getDropDownItem(){
        print(val);     //Need help here
      ;}
    return  Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 100),
      new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
        title: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Enter Provider Name Here',
            hintText: 'Provider Name',
  

        ),
            ),
          ),
}
```

In this ListTile, I am trying to collect the text value and print. I'm not even sure how to collect the value from the TextField. In the tutorials, this part was skipped. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the TextField value in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797045/how-to-get-the-textfield-value-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the controller in TextField

take controller variable

```
TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
```

in TextField set controller

```
TextField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Enter Provider Name Here',
            hintText: 'Provider Name',
  

        )
```

and you can get text using controller like

```
controller.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a  TextEditingController , as for example:

```
 TextEditingController _myController = TextEditingController();

final textfield = TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Enter Provider Name Here',
            hintText: 'Provider Name',
  

        ),
```

Then you can access this value using _myController.text property

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it:

1. declaring a variable and assigning value to it-

   ```
    String textvalue;

    TextField(
    onChanged: (value) {
        email = value;
    },
   ```

   )
2. by assigning TextEditingController()-

   ```
    TextEditingController textController;

    TextField(
    controller: textController,
    ),
   ```

now use it as

```
var value = textColtroller.text;
```