# how to store username and password from textfield using Shared preference in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-packages

I want to store two data(**user,password**) from two textfields using **shared preference package** in flutter

I created a function

```
saveData(String Name, String pass) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString(Name, pass);
}
```

Now I want to get the data from two textFields

> 

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('LOGIN'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.black12,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [TextField(), TextField()],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try initialize 2x controller

final nameController = TextEditingController();

final psswdController = TextEditingController();

in nex step add this controller to Text area like:

...

```
Column(
 children: [
   TextField(
    controller: nameController,
   ),
   TextField(
    controller: psswdController,
   ),
  ],
),
```

And when need get data from this areas call:

nameController.text

psswdController.text

like simple:

```
 saveData(nameController.text,psswdController.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to store data in shared preference, you have to store it like a key value pair. Your saveData method should look like this,

```
saveData(String key, String value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(key, value);
}
```

To get the value from textField you have to use textEditingController. To get more information you can follow this link
[How to get the TextField value in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797045/how-to-get-the-textfield-value-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

**I'm Trying to Solve your problem :**

*Create a button to save the data and two TextFields for users to enter their usernames and passwords:*

```
TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

...

TextField(
  controller: _usernameController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Username',
  ),
),
TextField(
  controller: _passwordController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Password',
  ),
  obscureText: true,
),
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('username', _usernameController.text);
    await prefs.setString('password', _passwordController.text);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Data saved successfully')),
    );
  },
  child: Text('Save'),
),
```

**You can use the getString() method to get the saved data Like This :**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String username = prefs.getString('username') ?? '';
String password = prefs.getString('password') ?? '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't saved name and password like that. `prefs.setString` have parameter key and value. Key for accessing the value of sharedprefs.

ex:

```
prefs.setString("username", "vidhu");
prefs.getString("username"); //"vidhu"
```

so, from your code above you need to adjust

```
saveData(String Name, String pass) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString("name", Name);
  prefs.setString("pass", pass);
}
```

and add TextFieldController for each textfield

```
Column(
 children: [
   TextField(
    controller: nameController,
   ),
   TextField(
    controller: passwordController,
   ),
  ],
)
```

then you can call `saveData()` from button

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed:saveData(nameController.text, passwordController.text), child: Text('Login')),
```

so when you access name and pass

```
print(prefs.getString("name")); //it will print your "Name"
print(prefs.getString("pass")); //it will print your "pass"
```